# IndexError: list index out of range while using nested loops

Tags: python-3.x

```
A = [34,23,1,24,75,33,54,8]
K = 60
solution=[]
for  i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(A)):
        v=solution[(A[i]+A[j])]
print(v)
```

Hi, I am trying to get the list with result of individual sums like: 34+23 34+1 34+24 and so on then next 23+1,23+24 and so on.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output. There is a good amount of information on the topic of IndexErrors, what part of this particular situation is not covered by existing resources?

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails since it's trying to set `v` to the `(A[i]+A[j])`th element of `solution`, which is empty, so that value doesn't exist.

If I understand what you're trying to do, then this should give the desired result.

```
A = [34,23,1,24,75,33,54,8]

v = [[A[x] + A[i] for i in range(x + 1, len(A))] for x in range(len(A))]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here,

*List index starts from 0 to the (n-1), where n is the len(list).*

So A(len(A)) doesn't exist. Which results in the error.

So to fix this replace

```
len(A)
```

by

```
len(A) - 1
```

inside all instances of range function.

Comment: but wouldnt that lead to ignoring the last element of the list. Will it pr processed in the loop?

Comment: we are meant to only run parent loop till 54 and not till 8. Anyway now I think about it maybe the error is in solution [ A[i] + A[j] ] it should have solution.append( A[i] + A[j] ).